# Is there any other way to use Alias in Sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working adjacent id exchange problem. I found one solution, it partly works.

```
SELECT tmp.id, tmp.student FROM
(
    SELECT id-1 AS id, student FROM seat WHERE id%2 = 0  -- even id -1
    UNION
    SELECT id+1 AS id, student FROM seat WHERE id%2 = 1  -- odd id +1

) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.id
```

I know the basic idea, but still confuse to the syntax or expression. I am wondering where the tmp comes from? Is the other way to use Alias in SQL?

Comment: tmp is the derived table name here

Comment: tmp is naming the table created in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample the tmp alias is changed in my_table_alias

```
SELECT my_table_alias.id, my_table_alias.student FROM
(
    SELECT id-1 AS id, student FROM seat WHERE id%2 = 0  -- even id -1
    UNION
    SELECT id+1 AS id, student FROM seat WHERE id%2 = 1  -- odd id +1

) my_table_alias
ORDER BY my_table_alias.id
```

This is introduced by the select ,,,, FROM ( subquery ) my_table_alias syntax: when you use a FROM( subquery ) you need a my_table_alias.

The table alias for then FROM(subquery) in mandatory if you want refer to the column coming from the FROM(subquery) in outer part of query.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN s.id % 2 = 0 THEN s.id - 1 ELSE s.id + 1 
        END) AS id,
       s.student
FROM seat s;
```

`UNION` is definitely not the right way to approach this problem.

Note that the `s` plays the same role as `tmp` in your question.  It is a table alias that names a table or subquery in the from clause.